# Power automate: flow dont not recognize xlsm. it change the format to xlsx

Tags: excel, xlsx, power-automate, xlsm

i have an issue with Microsoft Power Automate "Flows". i create Flows and wanted to import an Xlsm "Excel Document" to my flow. but it change to another Format "Xlsx". any one have an Idea ?

Best Regard.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91ADf.png)

Comment: So the desired situation is that the file remain "xlsm" and not be changed to "xlsx" during the import, right?  What measures have you already tried yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Automate Flows currently do not support Macro-enabled workbooks.
The request for the support of this are submitted, so if you too desire this feature - consider [upvoting](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Enable-actions-on-macro-enabled-files/idi-p/59194#comments)!

Answer (score 0):

1. get file ID by [Get File Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-file-metadata)
2. set the file ID into "File" in Excel Connector
3. then, You can use tables in *.xlsm.

[image]